# Laravel: boolean field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

One of my table fields is a boolean:

```
$table->boolean('correio')->default(0);
```

Here is the markup:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="correio" value="1"> Receber newsletter pelo correio?
</label>
```

And on controller:

```
Associado::create(request(['matricula', 'correio']));
```

But Laravel return this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'correio' cannot be null

Comment: If it's a checkbox, and it's unchecked, is the input even getting to the controller? By that, I mean, does it even know that the value (if unchecked) is supposed to be zero? (Basically, while the database knows that the default is zero, if the input isn't "arriving", is it trying to default it to null?)

Comment: Which version of Laravel is this? In 5.4 there is [ConvertEmptyStringsToNull](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L20) middleware which would probably fix this for you.

Comment: @Samsquanch thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding a hidden field to your table feels a bit dirty I'd personally set the default value within your model withing something along these lines:

```
protected $correio = false;
```

OR

```
protected $correio = "0"; //Quoted as laravel/eloquent *may* turn 0's(ints) to null
```

OR

You could just allow the column to be nullable?